# How to stop the currently selected Fragment from reloading in a Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Navigation drawer with 4 items each of which load 4 different fragments when clicked. All fragments contain a listview that displays data fetched from the web using an AsyncTask. My problem is this: Let's say I click on the second item and that fragment loads just fine. But when I click the same item again, the fragment also loads again. Is there a way I can stop the currently selected fragment from loading again? Maybe there's some way I can disable the currently selected item from being clicked. I'm sure there must be a better way. Thanks.

Comment: keep a check on currently visible fragment and the drawer item position being clicked or use a flag that contains the current position shown and everytime on list item click match that value if(!current_position == position_justclicked){// load the fragment here}

Answer (score 5):

You're probably adding your `Fragment` to a `FrameLayout` or any other kind of container. Before starting the transaction and replacing the Fragment in the container you can check if the Fragment you're trying to add is present already via the following code:

```
private void openFragment(Fragment newFragment){
    Fragment containerFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    if (containerFragment.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(newFragment.getClass().getName()))
       return;
    else
       // Start transaction and replace fragment
}
```